# How Vector<Vector> Receipt used as JasperReports DataSource with Java?

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a Vector receiptOrder and I want to print that receipt to thermal printer using `iReport`.

I get 3 classes:

- *MyDataSource* which implements *JRDataSource*
- *MyDataSourceProvider* which implements *JRDataSourceProvider*
- *JRBasicField* which implements *JRField*

How I can setup the `JasperReports` datasource with that vector?

- i made this changes .

  - load `jrxml` file

    ```
    JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load("c:/PrintReceipt.jrxml");
    JasperReport jr = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
    ```
  - pass `orderRows` which is `Vector<Vector>` to `MyDataSourceProvider` then Create `datasource`

    ```
    JRDataSourceProvider dsp = new MyDataSourceProvider(orderRows);
    JRDataSource dataSource = dsp.create(jr);
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr, new HashMap(), dataSource);
    JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, "c:/test.pdf");
    JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint);
    ```
- but JasperReport show me empty view and also `test.pdf` is empty .
- any idea ...?

Comment: Did you check the dataSource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I fixed *my problem* .
- The problem because of `MyDataSourceProvider fields` didn't match `ireport.jrxml fields`
- After i fix that problem  *All thing work good* .